# Enabling & disabling a textbox in razor view (ASP.Net MVC 3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html

I want to Enable or Disable a textbox based on the value (`Model.CompanyNameEnabled`).

The below code is not working. Please rectify.

```
@{
    string displayMode = (Model.CompanyNameEnabled) ? "" : "disabled = disabled";
    @Html.TextBox("CompanyName", "", new { displayMode })
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
@{
   object displayMode = (Model.CompanyNameEnabled) ? null : new {disabled = "disabled" };
   @Html.TextBox("CompanyName", "", displayMode)
}
```

You should pass htmlAttribute as anonymous object, with property names = html attribute names, property values = attribute values. Your mistake was that you were passing string instead of name=value pair

Comment: this approach doesn't work for me in MVC 5, the input renders as follows:

<input class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" displaymode="{ disabled = disabled }" id="txtPermitFromSearch" name="Permit.DescriptionFormatted" placeholder="Start typing a Permit # or an entity name." type="text" value="p-19, asdf asdf asdf , Brad Benson" autocomplete="off">

Answer (score 8):

`<input id="textbox1" type="text" @{@((Model.CompanyNameEnabled) ? null : new { disabled = "disabled" })}; />`

Haven't tested it, but should work

Comment: Works for me :)

Answer (score 4):

A simple approach:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone, new { disabled = "disabled", @class = "form-control" })`

Comment: To make this answer more complete have an @if(SetDisable) {}else{} and in the first set put the disable code, in the else, have an enabled textbox.

Answer (score 1):

As is already mentioned in this thread the suggested answer doesn't work in MVC5 anymore. There's actually an easy two step solution to that problem.

1. Assign a class to the HTML inputs you want to be disabled / enabled (id will do for a single item just as fine of course). In the example below I assigned a class ***'switch-disabled'*** to the input.

```
@Html.TextBox("CompanyName", "", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control switch-disable" } })
```

2. Use javascript(jquery) to enable / disable the *disabled* parameter in HTML. In my example below I do this at the page load.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(() => {
    if(@Model.CompanyNameEnabled)
    {
        $('.switch-disable').attr("disabled", false);
    }else{
        $('.switch-disable').attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
</script>
```