# How to programmatically enable/disable control in razor view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to enable/disable certain controls in the view depending on a condition. I try to use the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596665/enabling-disabling-a-textbox-in-razor-view-asp-net-mvc-3) but it did not work in my case. Currently I'm using the below (pseudo) code, which works perfectly, but it is insane to use it, since there are many entries like that.

What I need is a solution like in the linked question.
What I need is optimization of the following code since I have many more conditions like this one in the view.

```
@{ if (Model.ChargeCost == true)
 {
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Cost, new { @id="myId", @class = "form-control" })
 }
  else
 {
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Cost, new { @id = "myId", @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })
}
```

I'm using C#, MVC5 and Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Side note: `if Model.ChargeCost == true` is the same as `if Model.ChargeCost`

Comment: You have a miss-closed quote: `@class = "form-control, disabled = "disabled"` => `@class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled"`

Comment: You are using Visual Studio and not something like Notepad, right? Intellisense should have clued you in to your problem here.

Comment: @MelanciaUK You are right in both your comments. Thanks.Please read my update.

Comment: @Chris Pratt Yes, using VS 2013. but when I pasted into Notepad to simplify it, the error come up, but read the update please.

Comment: @BenJunior: 1) Complaining about downvotes is a losing battle. People downvote for all sorts of reasons, and trying to figure out why or worse fight with them about it is a total waste of time 2) If you don't want people to think that your problem is due to badly formatted code, then make sure your paste is formatted correctly. Our assumption is always going to be that this was a direct copy from your code, and since the code you posted won't compile, then there's your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You missed a `"` here:

```
@class = "form-control, disabled = "disabled"
```

This should be like below:

```
@class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled"
```

The same holds for this: `@id="myId", @class = "form-control`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go like this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Cost, new { @id = "myId", @class = "form-control", disabled = "disabled" })
```

Disabled is an attribute, not a css property.

Answer (score -1):

In your viewmodel, you should create a property that control it:

```
public string controlDisabled { get; set; }
```

And in the Action, depending your condition, set it to "disabled"

```
viewmodel.controlDisabled = condition ? "disabled" : "false";
```

And in view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Cost, new { @id = "myId", @class = "form-control", @disabled = Model.controlDisabled })
```

Comment: This is not the best solution in my case, but I can work on the idea. Did you actually test the code to see if it works?

Comment: adding adding disabled tag will always set the control to disabled no matter if u write disabled="false" or disabled="true" or disabled="xyz". So your solution wont work.

Comment: I second @UmerJavaid on this. There has been probably a change in the HTML5 specification since the time of the answer. This solution does not work.

Comment: The "view" part doesn't work. If you add a "disabled" attribute on an element it will be disabled, regardless of the value.