# ViewBag is intermittently null in view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I'm setting a boolean property on the `ViewBag` called `ReadOnly` in the controller.

I can access the property in certain places in the view successfully.

For example I can do:

```
<div>
   @ViewBag.ReadOnly
</div>
```

This will correctly output `True` or `False` to the view just fine.

However, when I try to pass the ReadOnly property as a parameter in the view then I get a null reference exception.

For example, this fails:

```
@Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(x => x.SplitBonus).Enable(!ViewBag.ReadOnly)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try below link. Seems same has been discussed here.

[Enabling & disabling a textbox in razor view (ASP.Net MVC 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6596665/enabling-disabling-a-textbox-in-razor-view-asp-net-mvc-3)

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the ViewBag property to something else (there may be a conflict) or add the ReadOnly property to the view model instead of the ViewBag.

```
@Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor(x => x.SplitBonus).Enable(!Model.ReadOnly)
```